# Protractor e2e tests throws error in browser.executeAsyncScript_

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I am trying to implement e2e test for our application.
But then my very first test case failed with below error.

```
Failed: Error while running testForAngular: javascript error: Unexpected 
identifier
  JavaScript stack:
  SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
      at callback (eval at executeAsyncScript (:457:5), <anonymous>:5:5)
      at check (eval at executeAsyncScript (:457:5), <anonymous>:50:7)
      at eval (eval at executeAsyncScript (:457:5), <anonymous>:53:3)
      at eval (eval at executeAsyncScript (:457:5), <anonymous>:54:4)
      at eval (eval at executeAsyncScript (:457:5), <anonymous>:55:63)
      at executeAsyncScript (<anonymous>:457:26)
      at <anonymous>:473:29
      at callFunction (<anonymous>:361:33)
      at <anonymous>:371:23
      at <anonymous>:372:3
    (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Can anyone please help me how can I resolve this error?

The error is from browser.js, from the promise 
this.executeAsyncScript_(clientSideScripts.testForAngular, msg('test for angular'), Math.floor(timeout / 1000), this.ng12Hybrid).

Just to be sure, I tried to test with angular site and that test case is passed, But the test case that tests the current page in my application fails

```
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

import { protractor } from 'protractor/built/ptor';

describe('Testing abc', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
  });

  it('should open the page', () => {
      browser.get('/abc');
      browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(actualUrl) {
          expect(actualUrl).toContain('/abc');
      });
  });

 it('should display page', () => {
    browser.get('https://angular.io');
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe('https://angular.io/');
 });

});
```

In the first test case, The block inside then of promise browser.getCurrentUrl() is not being executed.
Please help me with this

Comment: is your application angular?

Comment: @Madhan Yes.. It is an angular application

Comment: can you post config also, there could be a few things. And I still didn't get which `it` block fails - first or second?

Answer (score -1):

1. What is `actualUrl` ? Did you define it?
2. As far as I know, `browser.get` address should be only absolute path with protocol, e.g. `browser.get('https://angular.io/')`, not `browser.get('/something')`